# How to put a current date in QLabel in digits?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a problem with convert a current date.
I want to put a current date in a QLabel but i can't put a QDate type.

```
 QDate today;
      today=QDate::currentDate();
        datamiasto->setText("Data wystawienia: "+today+", xyz");
```

I can put it when i convert it to string but when i do it date is not in digits.
How can i put a digit date in a QLabel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
QDateTime dateTime = dateTime.currentDateTime();
QString dateTimeString = dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss");
```

[QDateTime::toString(const QString &format)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString) : Returns the datetime as a string. The format parameter determines the format of the result string. (give your custom format to the function)

[QDateTime::currentDateTime()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#currentDateTime) : Returns the current datetime, as reported by the system clock, in the local time zone.